# Returning viewbag asp.net mvc by ajax evokes memory leak

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks

Dealing up with asp.net MVC I faced with a problem of memory leak on server part.
I`m trying to refresh dataset from database using ajax query to my controller. Everything is working fine, but the memory usage growing proportionally to the queries count. So I need some help to clear memory after each of ajax query.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string incData)
    {
        DbEntities od = new DbEntities();
        IEnumerable<TestProc_Result> result = od.TestProc(incData);

        ViewBag.Proc_Result = result;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="form">
        <input id="textField" name="textField" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="con">
    @if(ViewBag.TestProc_Result != null)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TestProc_Result)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Email;
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.SenderName;
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.SenderSurname;
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Phone;
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery/ajax:

```
$("#textField").keypress(function (event) {

    var st = $("input[name='textField']").val() + event.key;
    var ser = { 'incData': st };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Index',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: ser,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#con").empty().append($(data).find('#con'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Memory usage in browser ? server ? where ? SQL server ?

Comment: Is this for Autocomplete suggestions?  I'd suggest something like https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for that.     Every time the controller is called, it will create  a new `DbEntities` instance and thus use more memory.  it SHOULD at some point perform garbage collection and release the memory.  This is basically automatic and something you *generally* shouldn't need to worry about.  it *is* possible that the construction of `DbEntities` allocates some resources that need to be manually released, but we can't see that from the example here.  Have you actually seen an error or just worried?

Comment: On server part as a part of vs2017 diagnostic tools. No errors, just worry about memory usage, because now procedure returns near 2 thousand record but with time this number will increase and I don`t want to have troubles later.